# Magento 2.2.4 Cannot create configurable product - Infinite loading in Step 2 :Attribute Values , error in console

Tags: product, configurable-product, attribute-set

I cant create a configurable product in Magento 2.2.4 the configurable product setup wizard gets stuck in step two where it asks to add attribute values.

I have tried creating static-content:deploy for both frontend and backend.
Also cleared cache, ran reindexer, disabled varnish cache. 
Still issue persists

Here is what I get in the console:

```
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
loader_old.min.js:5 Expected to start loader but did not find one in 
the dom_onAjaxSend @ loader_old.min.js:5
knockout.min.js:302 
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "visible: 
function(){return canCreateOption }"
Message: canCreateOption is not defined
at visible (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.min.js:268), <anonymous>:3:109)
at update (knockout.min.js:407)
at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.min.js:302)
at evaluateImmediate (knockout.min.js:183)
at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.min.js:204)
at knockout.min.js:302
at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.min.js:17)
at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.min.js:299)
at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.min.js:288)
at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.min.js:285)
```

[image: Console]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have Magento_Swatches module disabled.
If you want to keep it disabled, I believe you should override 
`vendor/magento/module-configurableproduct/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/attribute/steps/attributes_values.phtml` and comment out line 109:
`data-bind="click: $parent.createOption, visible: canCreateOption">`

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem myself and could not find an answer. However, while trying to fix a separate problem I stumbled upon the answer! You will need to enable the `Magento_ConfigurableProduct` module by using the following console commands:

`php bin/magento module:enable Magento_ConfigurableProduct`

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

If after running these your admin and front end stop showing images and CSS, then run

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

After this I was able to successfully create configurable products in the admin backend. Please let me know if this solution works for you.